# Complex DataBinding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I hope here can someone help me. I'm frustrated.

So here is my problem:

I've got a list of attributes, this attributes are properties for controls. Now I must have a binding between my propertgrid and the control themself. My control template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LabelVisualObject" DataType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LabelLayoutTemplateSelector}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Properties, Converter={StaticResource PropertyConverter}, ConverterParameter=VisualizationObjectTypeAttribute.Layout.Name}" Value="Layout_OneLine">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LabelOneLineVisualObject}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Properties, Converter={StaticResource PropertyConverter}, ConverterParameter=VisualizationObjectTypeAttribute.Layout.Name}" Value="Layout_TwoLines">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LabelTwoLinesVisualObject}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

PropertyConverter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable<IPropertyEditorAttribute>), typeof(object))]
public class PropertyConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is IEnumerable<IPropertyEditorAttribute>)
        {
            IEnumerable<IPropertyEditorAttribute> list = value as IEnumerable<IPropertyEditorAttribute>;

            foreach (IPropertyEditorAttribute cur in list)
            {
                if (cur.Name.Equals(parameter.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return cur.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Well, my oppertunity is, when the users changes the layout in the propertygrid, the trigger should react and change the template.

Does anyone know, how i can do this??

greets Patrik

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for a `DataTemplateSelector`.

You can find a short tutorial on it here: [How To Use A DataTemplateSelector](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Or from MSDN documentation:

- [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)
- [DataTemplateSelector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `ContentTemplateSelector` in place which sets the `ContentTemplate` and your try to set the `ContentTemplate` via a `Style`. Using both at the same time will not work, and the `ContentTemplateSelector` probably has [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as **local value**.